# Angular 5 Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to scroll the page to the element when page load. See below an example:

```
A) http://localhost:4200/#/test/test-history
B) http://localhost:4200/#/test/test-history#orderhistory
```

When I entered A), I want normal page load with no scroll effect.
When I entered B), I want to page load with scroll to the element.

In the HTML, I did `<div #orderhistory id="orderhistory" *ngIf="requestForCostShipment" >Bla Bla </div>`

And in the .ts file, under `ngOnInit()`, I did the following:

```
this.scroll('orderhistory');
```

and I wrote a function below:

```
scroll(id) {
      let el = document.getElementById(id);
      el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
    }
```

But, I faced the error:

> Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

I saw several post on this and applied several methods like `scrollToBottom();` but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**modified:**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      // Scroll (Anchor) Function to Order History
        this.scroll('orderhistory');
    }
```

The above is still showing error

> Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

Comment: Maybe when OnInit is executed the element orderhistory does not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since there is a condition to display the div you need to call the scroll function when the value of `requestForCostShipment` is true some thing like this

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      // Scroll (Anchor) Function to Order History
      if(this.requestForCostShipment){
        this.scroll('orderhistory');
       }
    }
```

or call `this.scroll('orderhistory');` where the value of `requestForCostShipment` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `el` is not rendererd yet. The reason for that is probably calling `this.scroll` from `ngOnInit` when elements does not exist in DOM. You should call `scroll` method in `ngAfterViewInit` which is simply called once after view is initialized.

Comment: Done and modified my post as above. The error is still there.

Comment: Then post your html structure, from where do you call to scroll to this element and where do you render orderHistory

Comment: is there a `*ngIf` condition on the div ?

Comment: yes, <div #orderhistory id="orderhistory" *ngIf="requestForCostShipment" >

Comment: @hana_wujira I have edited the HTML structure in my post

Comment: @hana_wujira so variable `requestForCostShipment` by the time when you try to scroll into element is set on `true` or `false`?

Comment: if the value of `requestForCostShipment` is false the div will not be render so `document.getElementById(id)` will return null so the value of `requestForCostShipment` have to be true

Answer (score 0):

Checking el != null may solve.